# Xamarin Android Unhandled Exception cannot be caught

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have implemented 3 global exception handlers in my MvvmCross Application Class OnCreate. However, there are still some unhandled exceptions that cannot be caught and crash my app. What could be the possible source and how can I catch them all? These are the exceptions handling being implemented:

```
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!

        // global exception handling
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += DroidErrorHandling.CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += DroidErrorHandling.TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += DroidErrorHandling.HandleAndroidExceptionAsync;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can handle ALL exceptions, I believe what you've listed above is the extent of what you can capture without doing some really weird anti-pattern stuff in xamarin android.

Comment: Really don't recommend this, if you catch all your errors this way, your program is not going to behave as expected, and you will not get error reports from Android Market when your users report them.

Comment: Instead of hiding the the error, the purpose of catching the exception is to log the stack trace for easy reporting. As it is intermittent, I need to find out the root cause to resolve.

Comment: As you see in visual studio app center's xamarin sdk, there are a lot of ways to catch exceptions using crash listeners and those you've already mentioned. Add their sdk to your app and see if exception is logged or not. If it gets logged that I'm sure about that, you've two solutions. 1- Relying on their services 2- Reading their open source code to find out what you should do on your own :)